# WatchKit: Extra argument completion in call error

Tags: xcode, watchkit, uiviewanimation

I am getting this error on my InterfaceController (watch Extension) but not on my iphone viewcontroller:

```
self.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    self.someButton.setAlpha(0.5)
}, completion: {

})
```

[image]

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UIKit, an [animate(alongsideTransition:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioncoordinator/1619300-animate) takes a completion parameter, but WatchKit's [animate(withDuration:animations:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1628239-animate) doesn't.